# Apache rewrite remove .jpg.html from URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, gallery

I've been trying to write a rewrite rule for apache to switch my gallery2 URLs to the gallery3 URL format:

```
Old url example linked: http://domain.com/gallery/photoalbumxyz/photo.jpg.html
New url example needed: http://domain.com/photos/photoalbumxyz/photo
```

Note that in the URL example above, "/photoalbumxyz/photo.jpg.html" is not an actual physical directory, it is just the way gallery2 rewrote "friendly" URLs.  I can rewrite the /gallery/ to /photos/ by using a rule like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /photos/$1   [QSA,L,R=301]
```

However I'm having trouble figuring out the matching and removal of the ".jpg.html" extension if it exists in combination with the /gallery/ -> /photos/ rewrite.  The regex matching I believe is going to be .jpg.html to escape the periods, but how do I write rules to remove the ".jpg.html" extension and rewrite the directory?

```
RewriteRule ^\.jpg\.html$ $1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /photos/$1   [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Edit:
Sorry!  I neglected earlier to mention the album URL formats can change (doesn't have to specify a photo, and can include sub albums), I've added some specific examples:

```
The url rewrite rule also needs to follow:
old: http://example.com/gallery
new: http://example.com/photos

old: http://example.com/gallery/album
new: http://example.com/photos/album

old: http://example.com/gallery/album/subalbum/
new: http://example.com/photos/album/subalbum/

old: http://example.com/gallery/album/subalbum/photo.jpg.html
new: http://example.com/photos/album/subalbum/photo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/gallery(.*?)(\.(jpe?g|gif|png)\.html)?$ /photos$1
```

Comment: This is working for the specific case - but I unfortunately realized I didn't qualify my question enough :(

The url rule also needs to follow:
`old: http://example.com/gallery
new: http://example.com/photos

old: http://example.com/gallery/album
new: http://example.com/photos/album

old: http://example.com/gallery/album/subalbum/
new: http://example.com/photos/album/subalbum/

old: http://example.com/gallery/album/subalbum/photo.jpg.html
new: http://example.com/photos/album/subalbum/photo`

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^/?gallery/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.(jpe?g|gif|png)\.html$ /photos/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

You don't need the `QSA` flag as query strings will automatically get appended if you don't have a `?` in your rule's target.

Comment: `^gallery/([^.]+)\.(jpe?g|gif|png)\.html$ /photos/$1` wouldn't this resume it?

Comment: This is working well for photos items in albums or subalbums (e.g. /gallery/album/photo.jpg.html or /gallery/album/subalbum/photo.jpg.html), but I need to also redirect when no photo is specified.  For example, /gallery should redirect to /photos, as should /gallery/album/subalbum to /photos/album/subalbum